# Visual Basic data file location

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know if there is a place to save a file that contains some data (that is used internally by the application - like a very tiny db). I don't want to save it to C:\file.txt. Is there a place where visual basic can hold these kind of files, like bin or something?

Thank you.

Comment: How much data? What kind of data?

Comment: Create/use an Xml file.  Simple to do.

Comment: A simple "," delimited text file. What I am worried about is to have the file in a more secured place, where it shouldn't be that easy to be found by the user and delete it by mistake. (I'm new to vb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the path in the VB object My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.AllUsersApplicationData or My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData to store what you want.

Comment: Ah, yes, this is what I was actually looking for. While a db was better to use, as others suggested, that's how the client wants it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what kind of data you are talking about (type, size and usage), but an embedded database may be just what you are looking for.

[SQL Server Compact Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices.

You can store data in Arrays, XML files, A SQL Database (Access, SQL Server, etc).
You can use your local user locations that are user specific.

IT all depends on how much data.